# Bootstrap navbar <li></li> to 100% width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem with my navbar. I need to do 100% width all of them. When I make:

```
.nav>li{
    width:100%;
}
```

It is not working as expected: [image]

without "width" i have standard bootstrap menu:
[image]

I need to have this:
[image]

Here is code of my navbar:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Thanks for any help :*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap provide a justified navbar.

Here is an example: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/

Just replace `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` by `<ul class="nav nav-justified">`

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/llhqh4PYsM

Comment: Now it is work but only when i have maximize chrome windows. When i will change width of my window. menu is going under Brand, and it dont like good :/